# Problem with file upload TCA after upgrading to TYPO3 10

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

On typo3v9 i had working file upload field with this TCA configuration:

```
    'image' => [
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'image upload',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'db',
            'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/folder',
            'show_thumbs' => 1,
            'size' => 5,
            'allowed' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'],
            'disallowed' => '',
         ],
     ],
```

i get this result:
[image]

but after migration to typo3v10 it does not work properly and give this result:

[image]

Someone have working solution for single file upload field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean internal_type=file ? That's deprecated. Here an example for image upload. However you can allow other types here too, I am sure you can find more info on that.

```
    'photos' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:xxx/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_xxx_domain_model_activity.photos',
        'config' =>
            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                'photos',
                [
                    'appearance' => [
                        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                    ],
                    'foreign_types' => [
                        '0' => [
                            'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                            'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'maxitems' => 30
                ],
                $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
            ),

    ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but that is not exactly what i want, In my solution i have single relation. In your we have mm relation. Shortest way for that can be found in fe_user.php:image and this solution is for type inline. I looking for solution working with type group.

Comment: I think there is no better solution that this which we have in tca for fe_user in image setting, i accept you answer because it is workin, it is not best but it is ok